# SOCKS5 tunneling through WebSocket with just using socket built-in library

Tags: python, sockets, networking, websocket, socks5

Overview of this problem is, I want to connect to the internet through websocket tunneling.

**Here is my expected timeline that should have working**:
[image]

My client device is only allowed to connect to the Cloudflare IPs, therefore I want my device (client) to connect the internet through websocket server as a proxy.

So my client device has tun2sock application, basically it's VPN. That app require socks5 address and port. It's succesfully connected, and I think there is no problem in socks5.

But I'm not sure about socks5 server script and websocket server script. Here is I provide my code both **socks5_server.py** when handling websocket connection and **websocket_server.py**. Note that I put some custom header in websocket header to indicate server what client want to connect to, it's named

```
Tunnel: TCP|addr|port
```

With that, ws server can parsing the custom ws header and create connection to the desired address and port.

Also I confident that my socks5 server has been following RFC1928, because I think there is no issue in socks5 server, but not for handling websocket connection inside socks5 server.

Here is *socks5_server.py*

```
import socket
from rfc1928_constants import *
from time import sleep

NUM_METHOD = 1
METHOD_REQ = VER_5 + NUM_METHOD.to_bytes(1, 'big') + METHOD_NOAUTHENTICATIONREQUIRED
METHOD_RES = VER_5 + METHOD_NOAUTHENTICATIONREQUIRED

SOCKS5_SERVER_IP = '192.168.43.248'
SOCKS5_SERVER_PORT = 9999

socks5clients: list = []

def start_ws_tunnel(DST_ADDR: str, DST_PORT: int, clientsock: socket.socket, clientaddr: tuple[str, int]):

  # Websocket client initialization...
  ws = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  wsreq: bytes = b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n" \
    b"Host: wstun.ikhwanperwira.my.id\r\n" \
    b"Tunnel: TCP|"+DST_ADDR.encode()+b"|"+str(DST_PORT).encode()+b"\r\n" \
    b"Upgrade: websocket\r\n" \
    b"Connection: Upgrade\r\n" \
    b"Sec-WebSocket-Key: x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==\r\n" \
    b"Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n\r\n"
  ws.connect(('104.26.6.171', 80)) # Connect to Cloudflare IP
  ws.send(wsreq)
  wsres: bytes = ws.recv(1024)
  if not b"101 Switching Protocols" in wsres[:64]:
    raise Exception(f"Websocket server didn't return 101 Switching Protocols! {wsres}")
  print('Switching protocol accepted from websocket server!')
  
  while 1:
    req = clientsock.recv(4096)
    if not req:
      print('connection closed from client')
      break

    succeed = ws.send(req)
    if succeed != len(req):
      print('failed on forwarding request from client to server')
      break

    res = ws.recv(4096)
    if not res:
      print('connection closed from server')
      break

    succeed = clientsock.send(res)
    if succeed != len(res):
      print('failed on forwarding response from server to client')
      break

  print('Connection closed:', clientaddr)
  ws.close()
  clientsock.close()
  del ws
  del clientsock
  del clientaddr

def client_collector(interrupt):
  global socks5clients
  
  tcpsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  tcpsocket.bind((SOCKS5_SERVER_IP, SOCKS5_SERVER_PORT))
  tcpsocket.listen(5)

  while not interrupt.is_set():
    socks5clients.append(tcpsocket.accept())

def tcp_handler(interrupt):
  from threading import Thread
  global socks5clients

  while not interrupt.is_set():
    try:
      for client in socks5clients:
        clientsock, clientaddr = client
        method_req = clientsock.recv(1024)
        VER = method_req[0:1]
        NMETHOD = method_req[1:2]
        METHODS = method_req[2:2+int.from_bytes(NMETHOD, 'big')]
        if method_req == METHOD_REQ:
          method_res = METHOD_RES
          nbytes_sent = clientsock.send(method_res)
          if nbytes_sent != len(method_res):
            raise Exception('Failed to send method response!')
        else:
          raise Exception(f'Invalid method request! {METHOD_REQ}')
        socks5req: bytes = clientsock.recv(1024)
        VER: bytes = socks5req[0:1]
        CMD: bytes = socks5req[1:2]
        RSV: bytes = socks5req[2:3]
        ATYP = socks5req[3:4]
        if VER != VER_5:
          raise Exception('Invalid version number!')
        if CMD not in [CMD_CONNECT, CMD_BIND, CMD_UDP]:
          raise Exception('Invalid command!')
        if RSV != TCP_RSV:
          raise Exception('Invalid reserved byte!')
        
        BND_ADDR, BND_PORT = SOCKS5_SERVER_IP, SOCKS5_SERVER_PORT
        # if CMD == CMD_UDP:
        #   print('UDP request detected on:', clientaddr)
        
        if ATYP == ATYP_IPV4:
          DST_ADDR_LEN = ATYP_IPV4_LEN
          DST_ADDR = socket.inet_ntoa(socks5req[4:4+DST_ADDR_LEN])
          DST_PORT = int.from_bytes(socks5req[4+DST_ADDR_LEN:4+DST_ADDR_LEN+2], 'big')
          socks5res = VER_5 + REP_SUCCEEDED + TCP_RSV + ATYP_IPV4 + socket.inet_aton(BND_ADDR) + BND_PORT.to_bytes(2, 'big')
        elif ATYP == ATYP_IPV6:
          DST_ADDR_LEN = ATYP_IPV6_LEN
          DST_ADDR = socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, socks5req[4:4+DST_ADDR_LEN])
          DST_PORT = int.from_bytes(socks5req[4+DST_ADDR_LEN:4+DST_ADDR_LEN+2], 'big')
          socks5res = VER_5 + REP_SUCCEEDED + TCP_RSV + ATYP_IPV4 + socket.inet_aton(BND_ADDR) + BND_PORT.to_bytes(2, 'big')
        elif ATYP == ATYP_DNS:
          DST_ADDR_LEN = int.from_bytes(socks5req[4:5], 'big')
          DST_ADDR = socks5req[5:5+DST_ADDR_LEN].decode('ascii')
          DST_PORT = int.from_bytes(socks5req[5+DST_ADDR_LEN:5+DST_ADDR_LEN+2], 'big')
          socks5res = VER_5 + REP_SUCCEEDED + TCP_RSV + ATYP_IPV4 + socket.inet_aton(BND_ADDR) + BND_PORT.to_bytes(2, 'big')
        
        clientsock.send(socks5res)

        if CMD != CMD_UDP:
          # if DST_ADDR == '93.184.216.34':
          Thread(target=start_ws_tunnel, args=(DST_ADDR, DST_PORT, clientsock, clientaddr, )).start()

        socks5clients.remove(client)
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      pass

def udp_handler(interrupt):
  udpsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
  udpsocket.bind((SOCKS5_SERVER_IP, SOCKS5_SERVER_PORT))

  while not interrupt.is_set():
    try:
      udpreq, clientaddr = udpsocket.recvfrom(2048)
      RSV = udpreq[0:2]
      FRAG = udpreq[2:3]
      ATYP = udpreq[3:4]

      if ATYP == ATYP_IPV4:
        DST_ADDR_LEN = ATYP_IPV4_LEN
        DST_ADDR = socket.inet_ntoa(udpreq[4:4+DST_ADDR_LEN])
        offset = 4
      elif ATYP == ATYP_IPV6:
        DST_ADDR_LEN = ATYP_IPV6_LEN
        DST_ADDR = socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, udpreq[4:4+DST_ADDR_LEN])
        offset = 4
      elif ATYP == ATYP_DNS:
        DST_ADDR_LEN = int.from_bytes(udpreq[4:5], 'big')
        DST_ADDR = udpreq[5:5+DST_ADDR_LEN].decode('ascii')
        offset = 5
      else:
        raise Exception('Invalid address type!')
      
      DST_PORT = int.from_bytes(udpreq[offset+DST_ADDR_LEN:offset+DST_ADDR_LEN+2], 'big')
      data = udpreq[offset+DST_ADDR_LEN+2:]
      udpres = udpreq[:offset+DST_ADDR_LEN+2] + (b'UDP:'+ data)
      if DST_ADDR == '104.26.6.171':
        print(clientaddr, 'UDP', (DST_ADDR, DST_PORT), data, sep=' -> ')
        udpsocket.sendto(udpres, clientaddr)
      sleep(1)
    except:
      pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  from threading import Thread, Event

  interrupt = Event()

  client_collector_thread = Thread(target=client_collector, args=(interrupt, ))
  tcp_thread = Thread(target=tcp_handler, args=(interrupt, ))
  udp_thread = Thread(target=udp_handler, args=(interrupt, ))

  client_collector_thread.start()
  tcp_thread.start()
  udp_thread.start()

  input("Press enter to stop program...")
  interrupt.set()

  client_collector_thread.join()
  tcp_thread.join()
  udp_thread.join()
```

And here is:
**websocket_server.py**

```
import socket

def tunnel_connect(clientsock, clientaddr, dst_addr, dst_port):

  tunsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  tunsock.bind(("10.1.12.255", 0))
  try:
    print(f"Connecting {(dst_addr, int(dst_port))}")
    tunsock.connect((dst_addr, int(dst_port)))
  except Exception as e:
    print(f'connection closed earlier when connecting {(dst_addr, int(dst_port))}:', e)
    clientsock.close()
    tunsock.close()
    del clientsock
    del tunsock
    return
  
  while 1:
    req = clientsock.recv(4096)
    if not req:
      print('connection closed from client')
      break

    succeed = tunsock.send(req)
    if succeed != len(req):
      print('failed on forwarding request from client to server')
      break

    res = tunsock.recv(4096)
    if not res:
      print('connection closed from server')
      break

    succeed = clientsock.send(res)
    if succeed != len(res):
      print('failed on forwarding response from server to client')
      break

  # print("tunsock thread closed!")
  tunsock.close()
  clientsock.close()
  del clientsock
  del tunsock


def handle_client(client_socket, client_addr):
  from threading import Thread

  try:
    # Receive data from the client
    request = client_socket.recv(4096)
    
    if not request:
      print('Failed to connect!')
      client_socket.close()
      return
    
    if b'x3JJHMbDL1EzLkh9GBhXDw==' in request:
      req_str = request.decode('utf-8')
      param = 'Tunnel: '
      start_index = req_str.find(param)
      stop_index = req_str.find("\r\n", start_index+len(param))
      tunnel_val = req_str[start_index:stop_index].strip()
      proto, dst_addr, dst_port = tunnel_val.split('|')
      client_socket.send(b"HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n" \
        b"Upgrade: websocket\r\n" \
        b"Connection: Upgrade\r\n" \
        b"Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=\r\n\r\n")
    else:
      print('Invalid ws key.')
      client_socket.close()
      return
  except:
    return
  
  Thread(target=tunnel_connect, args=(client_socket, client_addr, dst_addr, dst_port,)).start()

  # while 1:
  #   request = client_socket.recv(4096)
  #   if not request:
  #     break
    # client_socket.send(b'ECHO:'+request)
    # client_socket.send('|'.join([proto, dst_addr, dst_port]).encode())


  # # Close the client socket
  # print('Connection closed:', client_addr)
  # client_socket.close()

def main():
  from threading import Thread
  # Create a socket object
  server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

  # Allow address reuse
  server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

  # Bind to localhost and port 3333
  server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 3333))

  # Listen for incoming connections
  server_socket.listen(5)

  print("Listening on port 3333...")

  while True:
    # Accept connections from client
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    print("Accepted connection from", addr)
    Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, addr, )).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Here is sample of **websocket_server.py** output:

```
Listening on port 3333...
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34544)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34548)
Connecting ('api.anythinktech.com', 443)
Connecting ('report.apkpure.net', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34550)
Connecting ('net.mtgglobals.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34554)
Connecting ('mqtt-mini.facebook.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34564)
Connecting ('googleads.g.doubleclick.net', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34574)
Connecting ('www.gstatic.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34578)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34590)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34602)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34610)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34618)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34622)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34636)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34638)
Connecting ('optimizationguide-pa.googleapis.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34646)
Connecting ('analytics-tcp.mintegral.net', 9377)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34652)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34666)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34674)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 34676)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59558)
Connecting ('svibeacon.onezapp.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59560)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59572)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59584)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59590)
Connecting ('api.myadsget.com', 80)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59606)
Connecting ('svibeacon.onezapp.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59610)
Connecting ('googleads.g.doubleclick.net', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59620)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59626)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59628)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59638)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59650)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 59656)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from server
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41930)
Connecting ('report.apkpure.net', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41938)
Connecting ('svibeacon.onezapp.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41944)
Connecting ('report.apkpure.net', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41948)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41962)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41966)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41982)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 41998)
Connecting ('net.mtgglobals.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 53190)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 53194)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 53204)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38670)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38672)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38684)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38690)
Connecting ('beacons.gcp.gvt2.com', 443)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38692)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38700)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38712)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38728)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38742)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38746)
Connecting ('discover-pa.googleapis.com', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from server
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38762)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38772)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38774)
Connecting ('googleads.g.doubleclick.net', 443)
Connecting ('clients4.google.com', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38790)
Connecting ('googleads.g.doubleclick.net', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38800)
Connecting ('clientservices.googleapis.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38808)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38812)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52922)
Connecting ('beacons.gvt2.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52926)
Connecting ('svibeacon.onezapp.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52508)
Connecting ('exp5.www.linkedin.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52514)
Connecting ('74.125.130.94', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52526)
Connecting ('exp5.www.linkedin.com', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38228)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38232)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38242)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38254)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38260)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38276)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38288)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38304)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38312)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38316)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38320)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38330)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38342)
Connecting ('android.apis.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 38350)
Connecting ('optimizationguide-pa.googleapis.com', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52456)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52460)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52468)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52470)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52478)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52482)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52484)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52496)
Connecting ('api.anythinktech.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52510)
Connecting ('api.myadsget.com', 80)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52518)
Connecting ('svibeacon.onezapp.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52528)
Connecting ('net.mtgglobals.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52540)
Connecting ('configure-tcp-android.mtgglobals.com', 9377)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52550)
Connecting ('clients4.google.com', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52566)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52582)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52596)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52610)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52618)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 52622)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36018)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36034)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36050)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36054)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36064)
Connecting ('report.apkpure.net', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36074)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36078)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 36092)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58704)
Connecting ('accounts.google.com', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58710)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58714)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58722)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58736)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58750)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58760)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58768)
Connecting ('dns.google', 443)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58770)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58776)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58786)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58798)
Connecting ('twitter.com', 443)
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58812)
Connecting ('www.google.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58826)
Connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80)
connection closed earlier when connecting ('27.112.79.120', 80): [Errno 111] Connection refused
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58836)
Connecting ('abs.twimg.com', 443)
Accepted connection from ('127.0.0.1', 58846)
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
connection closed from client
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/isysrg/Koding/wstun/wsserver.py", line 114, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/isysrg/Koding/wstun/wsserver.py", line 108, in main
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 293, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
KeyboardInterrupt
^CException ignored in: <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1567, in _shutdown
    lock.acquire()
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Actually, it's worked, I tried to connect my client to socks5 server through socks5 client VPN app. But it's only worked on `example.com` ip which is **93.184.216.34** returning response *404 Not Found* that can be considered as successful connection. The other rest accessing another address on internet such as **google.com** is just stuck on indefinitely loading.